# Server sent event data not displaying in browser

Tags: python, twisted, server-sent-events

I am new to Python and networking. I am trying some Python code at server side to display some continous data on my client browser. I have taken this sample code from net itself. The problem is that this code works fine on local machine when i try to access it my browser using localhost but doesn't works when i try to access it from other machine. In Ubuntu i doesn't get any data on my browser but in windows i get all data pushed on my browser when i stop the server code. I am using Twisted and Flask in Python for this. Here is the code i am trying:

```
import random
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.internet import reactor
import time

from flask import Flask, request, Response
app = Flask(__name__)

def event_stream():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        yield 'data: %d\n\n' % count
        time.sleep(5)
        print 'data sent...'

@app.route('/my_event_source')
def sse_request():
    return Response(
            event_stream(),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')

@app.route('/')
def page():
    return '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="EventSource.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                    function() {
                        sse = new EventSource('/my_event_source');
                        sse.onmessage = function(message) {
                            console.log('A message has arrived!');
                            $('#output').append('<li>'+message.data+'</li>');
                        }
                    })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World Example to implement Server Sent Event using Twisted in Python...</h2>
        <ul id="output"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'starting server...'
    resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), app)
    site = Site(resource)
    reactor.listenTCP(9999, site)
    reactor.run()
```

Can someone help me why the data is not getting displayed when i am trying to access it from other machine (or how can i debug it). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This works correctly for me on a local machine, across a LAN, and on a cloud server.  Please provide more details about your environment, about your browser, about the exact behavior you're seeing.

Comment: If you want to do simple two-way-web stuff like this, you may be interested in [Klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein), which gives a Flask-like wrapper to Twisted, and allows you to do things with timed events rather than threads blocked in `time.sleep`.  This would allow you to support more concurrent users and have to worry less about coordinating access to shared resources.  That said, your example here *should* work fine - as I said above, it does for me.

Comment: @Glyph: i am looking for server side stuff only(i.e. one way stuff only). On localhost i am trying with Windows 7. On Windows, it works only on Chrome browser(after removing proxy) but doesn't work on Firefox. I am also trying to access this code(deployed on Ubuntu 14) from my Windows machine but didn't get any data on any of the browser..any help...

Comment: "removing proxy"? what proxy? have you tried different machines as clients?  This seems to work fine for me on Windows as well.

Comment: My office internal network has some proxy settings which was creating some problem.Yes, i tried to access it from different machines as well. @Glyph : did you run this script on unix/linux and then tried to access it from the browser on windows?